# Excel output in Panda - TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to troubleshoot this error message in the code I am in the middle of creating. When I run it and print(df) it gives me the output that I should have, however when I try to export to .xlsx it's giving me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Attr_Editor_Excel/Extract_xlsx.py", line 38, in
>
> df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= sheet_name, startrow=0, startcol=0,
>   index=False, header=False)
>
> File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1424,
>   in to_excel
>       engine=engine)
>
> File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line
>   628, in write
>       freeze_panes=freeze_panes)
>
> File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1558, in
>   write_cells
>       if sheet_name in self.sheets:
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I've tried for over an hour to try to troubleshoot this error, but haven't. So I'm doing my last resort at asking you guys.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('C:/Users/PCTR261010/Desktop/Attribute Convert')
FileList = glob.glob('*.txt')

for fname in FileList:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(fname), 'html.parser')

# START----CODE-----CODE-----CODE----CODE-----CODE-----CODE----CODE-----CODE-----CODE
    attributes = dict()

    attributes['Description']=([soup.find('description').text])
    attributes['Date']=([soup.find('date').text])
    attributes['TIME']=([soup.find('time').text])
    attributes['MPCC']=([soup.find('leafname').text])

    #still working on this, needs to be column headers in output
    attributes['A']=([x.find('name').text for x in soup.find_all('attributedefinition')])
    attributes['B']=([x.find('displayname').text for x in soup.find_all('attributedefinition')])

    df = pd.DataFrame(list(attributes.items()))

    data = soup.find('data').text #product data

    for partno in data.split('\n'):
        if partno:
            attributes['partno']=(partno.split('\t'))

# END----CODE-----CODE-----CODE----CODE-----CODE-----CODE----CODE-----CODE-----CODE

    report_path = 'Attribute Excel Files'
    if not os.path.exists(report_path):
        os.makedirs(report_path)

        sheet_name = ([soup.find('leafname').text])
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(fname + '.xlsx'), engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= sheet_name, startrow=0, startcol=0, index=False, header=False)

        workbook = writer.book
        workbook.filename = (fname + '.xlsx')
        worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]  # Names sheet name

        writer.save()
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
<HEADER>
<OPERATOR> NAPA PCC Export </OPERATOR>
<DESCRIPTION>  3686281-PFQ,Motor Oil - 1 qt  </DESCRIPTION>
<EMAIL>  </EMAIL>
<DATE> Wednesday, April 04, 2018 </DATE>
<TIME> 08:09 AM </TIME>
</HEADER>

<leafname>3686281</leafname>
<attributes>
<attributedefinition>
<name>Partnumber</name>
<displayname>Part number</displayname>
<guidetext>Part number and line abbreviation</guidetext>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>GPC_highmileageformula</name>
<displayname>High Mileage Formula</displayname>
<guidetext>High Mileage Formula</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>hard</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>GPC_synthetic</name>
<displayname>Synthetic</displayname>
<guidetext>Synthetic</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>hard</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>GPC_motoroilbrand</name>
<displayname>Brand</displayname>
<guidetext>Motor Oil Brand</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>hard</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>GPC_motoroilsubbrand</name>
<displayname>Sub Brand</displayname>
<guidetext>Motor Oil Sub Brand</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>hard</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_28892</name>
<displayname>Manufacturer Part Number</displayname>
<guidetext>Mfg Part Number</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>GPC_containersize</name>
<displayname>Container Size</displayname>
<guidetext>Container Size</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>hard</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>GPC_motoroilweightrating</name>
<displayname>Motor Oil Weight Rating</displayname>
<guidetext>Motor Oil Weight Rating</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>hard</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>GPC_motoroilstyleandtype</name>
<displayname>Motor Oil Style and Type</displayname>
<guidetext>Motor Oil Style and Type</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>hard</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>GPC_motoroilapirating</name>
<displayname>Motor Oil API Rating</displayname>
<guidetext>Motor Oil API Rating</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>hard</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_3534119</name>
<displayname>Motor Oil Specifications</displayname>
<guidetext>Motor Oil Specifications</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>GPC_dexosrating</name>
<displayname>Dexos Rating</displayname>
<guidetext>Dexos Rating</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>hard</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_23355</name>
<displayname>Product Features</displayname>
<guidetext>Product Features</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_2388</name>
<displayname>Packaging</displayname>
<guidetext>Type of Packaging</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_26544</name>
<displayname>Features & Benefits</displayname>
<guidetext>Features & Benefits</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_26689</name>
<displayname>Features & Benefits</displayname>
<guidetext>Features & Benefits</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_26974</name>
<displayname>Features & Benefits</displayname>
<guidetext>Features & Benefits</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_27547</name>
<displayname>Features & Benefits</displayname>
<guidetext>Features & Benefits - 2</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_27548</name>
<displayname>Features & Benefits</displayname>
<guidetext>Features & Benefits - 3</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_27549</name>
<displayname>Features & Benefits</displayname>
<guidetext>Features & Benefits - 4</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_27550</name>
<displayname>Features & Benefits</displayname>
<guidetext>Features & Benefits - 5</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_27551</name>
<displayname>Features & Benefits</displayname>
<guidetext>Features & Benefits - 6</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_27552</name>
<displayname>Features & Benefits</displayname>
<guidetext>Features & Benefits - 7</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_27553</name>
<displayname>Features & Benefits</displayname>
<guidetext>Features & Benefits - 8</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

<attributedefinition>
<name>PHdb_27554</name>
<displayname>Features & Benefits</displayname>
<guidetext>Features & Benefits - 9</guidetext>
<values>
<domaintype>soft</domaintype>
<VALUELIST>
</VALUELIST>
</values>
</attributedefinition>

</attributes>


<DATA>
PF0W20DEXQT     Yes NAPA    Proformer       1 qt    0W20    Synthetic   SN  ILSAC GF-5  Dexos 1 Gen 2   NAPA PROFORMER 0W20 SYNTHETIC DEXOS® MOTOR OIL is a superiorquality synthetic motor oil specially formulated from 100% pure virgin base oil and highperformance additives.  Bottle                                              
PF0W20SYQT      Yes NAPA    Proformer       1 qt    0W20    Synthetic   SN  ILSAC GF-5      NAPA PROFORMER 0W20 SYNTHETIC MOTOR OIL is a superior?quality synthetic motor oil specially formulated from 100% pure virgin base oil and highperformance additives.    Bottle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sheet_name = ([soup.find('leafname').text])`

The fact that `sheet_name` is a list causes `if sheet_name in self.sheets:` to fail since `self.sheets` is a dictionary, meaning `sheet_name in self.sheets` is going to attempt hashing `sheet_name` hence the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Change `sheet_name` to a string:

```
sheet_name = soup.find('leafname').text
```

Comment: That would do it, of course. Thanks for spotting my error, that I couldn't